# Adding CSS pseudo elements inline

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to add pseudo element declaration inline. For eg. can I do the following inline ?

```
.XYZ:after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;}

<div class="XYZ"></div> /*Pseudo element should be declarer inline*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to apply pseudo selectors via inline CSS, that's only possible from within `<style></style>` blocks or external stylesheet file.

Imagine constructing an email template with inline pseudo selector that uses `content` property, bad guys could have done the harm I suppose. So it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. pseudo element stylings may only be declared in an external stylesheet or inside `<style></style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Hacss](https://hacss.io/) may provide the experience you're looking for.

[Demo](https://basement.hacss.io/#NoIgPAJglgbgBAYwDYEMDOaC8AdEAuPFAMwBcBTAJwG8EB7AO3MbwHIBCFgbgF9cA+AHJQEZOCVpwAtmTIk4AT1oBXMAHpoMPiAA0IHSAAKaMkogSAokjLTGcACLXaIALpA)